# Shouldn't The Term Room-Temperature Superconductivity be Scrapped?

Tags: superconductivity

There have been headlines claiming that the long-sought Room-Temperature Superconductivity has finally been achieved, and it is technically correct. But when this notion was first conjectured, there was no reason to expect that pressure would be relevant. So basically extremely-low temperature is being replaced by extremely-high pressure so isn't Room-Temperature Superconductivity intentionally misleading. Shouldn't we call it High Pressure Superconductivity. It seems very deceitful, because STP-Superconductivity has never been discovered, there is no proof that is it possible and STP-Superconductivity is was Room-Temperature Superconductivity was originally meant by. Right?

Comment: Temperature is a critical parameter, so no.

Comment: You can use "ambient conditions" if you want. But achieving superconductivity at high (room) temperatures (even if the pressures are also high) is an important feat. In BCS theory, quantities as the coherence length and the gap depend on the temperature (not the pressure). And these systems seem to respect BCS. Many questions arise because of the temperature, in particular the comparison of the coherence length with the lattice parameter. So using RT superconductivity is meaningful (at least from the scientific, if not technological, stand point) even if the pressure is high.